# Is there any "Derivative Mean Value" for double integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if **f** is analytic on $D(z_o,R)$ then for every then for any $0\lt r\lt R$,
$$f(z_o)=\frac{1}{πr^2}\iint_{D(z_o,R)} f(x+iy)\ dx\ dy$$

This is the mean value formula for double integrals
can we say something similar for the derivative of f?
for example:

$$f'(z_o)=\frac{1}{πr^2}\iint_{D(z_o,R)} f'(x+iy)\ dx\ dy$$

I want to get an expiration connecting $f'(0)$ and $\iint_{D(0,1)}$

Comment: $f'$ is analytic isn't it?

Comment: I get it for free?

Comment: Of course, and free is good.

Comment: The problem is that I spent 3 hours until I ask and get this trivial thing. I m ok now, I solved my exercise. Thank you very much.